# connect to ethereum from web3

Tags: web3js

i have tried following the mentioned steps at  [this](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/99/Interacting-with-a-Smart-Contract-through-Web3.js-(Tutorial))
but this connects to remix IDE. i want to connect to real ethereum wallet and use ether from there. please help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want connect with main net or testnet (Ropsten,RinkeBy,Kovan) then you can use infura https://blog.infura.io/getting-started-with-infura-28e41844cc89 . you can also get details from here. After that you need to deploy you contract from truffle, you can start from here https://medium.com/@gus_tavo_guim/using-truffle-to-create-and-deploy-smart-contracts-95d65df626a2  or you can deploy directly on ethreum wallet https://www.codeooze.com/blockchain/ethereum-wallet-private-chain-deploy/

If you are using ethereum wallet GUI then just you need ABI. which you can get from Remix IDE. And Create wallet address and then you can deploy your contract.